# Regex for alphanumeric and special characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i tried to make a regex for my Address column the code is:

```
var str = "97sadf []#-.'";
var regx = /^[a-zA-z0-9\x|]|[|-|'|.]*$/;

if(str.match(regx))
   document.write('Correct!');
else
    document.write('Incorrect!');
```

the special character i want that is `][#-.` the given code return me the correct match but if i add another kind of the special character like `@%` then the correct result i got, but i want the incorrect result.

i don't know where i did wrong please help me to make right..

EDIT: Sorry guys but the one thing i have to discuss with you that is there is no necessary  to enter the special characters that i mentioned `][#-.`, but if the someone enter other then the given special character then should return the incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regex (assuming you want uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, spaces and special characters `[].-#'`) is:

```
var regx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.\-#']*$/
```

There are a couple things breaking your code.

First, `[`, `]`, `-` and `.` have special meaning, and must be escaped (prefixed with `\`).

`\x` checks for line breaks, where we want spaces (`\s`).

Next, lets look at the structure; for simplicity's sake, lets simplify to `^[abc]|[def]*$`.   (`abc` and `def` being your two blocks of character types).  Since the `*` is attached to the second block, it is saying one instance of `[abc]` or any number of `[def]`.

Finally, we don't need `|` inside of brackets, becuase they already mean one character contained within them (already behaves like an or).

Comment: thanks a lot man, you are absolutely right, but you missed a single `'` that i added i found my mistake what i did, thanks again..

Comment: +1 for your powers of deduction into the question.  I was trying to figure out why the OP was searching for such an odd format String.  :-)